# Linker issues in C++ / ObjC

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode

I'm porting a sizeable codebase to iOS. The simplified version of my scenario is as follows:

- I have a C++ library, built from the command line. I can run code from it from the iOS simulator, so I believe it's correctly built.
- I have the skeleton iOS application created by Xcode

I want to add logging to the C++ library. I have a trace() method which takes `fmt, ...`. I compile that .cpp using `-x Objective-c++`, the code is as follows:

```
void trace (const char* sFmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, sFmt);

    NSString* sFmt2 = [ NSString stringWithUTF8String: sFmt ];
    NSLogv(sFmt2, args);

    va_end(args);
}
```

The library compiles just fine. However, when I try to link the app, I get a linker error:

```
  ".objc_class_name_NSString", referenced from: literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSString in lib.a(trace.o)
```

This is strange because I can use NSString and NSLog from a .mm file in the project itself. The Foundation framework is linked. Moreover, just to test, instead of calling NSString from my library I added a helper foobar() to the .mm in the project, which does this

```
void foobar (const char* sFmt)
{
    NSLog([NSString stringWithUTF8String:sFmt]);
}
```

When this is called from the library function above, it works!

Everything I read about this kind of error involves a "just updated my SDK" scenario, which is not my case. I started doing iOS stuff literally two days ago, I haven't changed the default project settings, etc.

My guess is that name mangling is failing at some point, because I know NSString is indeed linked, but it seems the name refrenced by the library is different to the linked one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by using `libtool` instead of `ld`, passing it `-framework Foundation`, and passing `-fobjc-abi-version=2` to `gcc`.

Comment: I believe this is equivalent to suggestion #1 in my answer.

Comment: @ipmcc: not really. The switch that makes the difference is -fobjc-abi-version=2. I believe -framework Foundation is redundant there since libtool doesn't actually do any kind of linking when making a static lib. A switch that selects an ABI version is completely consistent with my problem that looked like a name mangling issue since the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Your linker output indicates that your command-line-built library is lib.a, which indicates to me that it's a static library. I'd guess that, not being a dylib, it doesn't know how to use the dyloader to find missing symbols at runtime. Relatedly, I suspect that the iOS project will link in these System libraries dynamically (even though non-OS developers can't create dynamic frameworks), whereas your static C++ library will expect those symbols to be resolved at link time.

I suspect that any of these three things would resolve the issue: (in descending order of attractiveness)

1. statically link against the right libraries when building the C++ library
2. make the C++ library a dylib instead of a static library (so it will expect to find missing symbols at runtime using the dyloader)
3. link your whole app statically (so the NSString class symbols are present at app link time) (This is a bad idea, if it's even possible at all, but would likely solve the problem.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I was under the impression that dylibs weren't supported in iOS. I'll give it a try!

Comment: Ah, yeah. I thought it was dynamic linked *frameworks* that were disallowed but I checked and it appears to be all non-OS dynamic libraries, which naturally includes all dynamic linked frameworks.  Anyway, I guess it's down to options #1 or #3.